# R plot title with uppercase and italic

Tags: r, plot, uppercase, italic

I'm trying to make a title with italic and uppercase text. Right now I have this code line:

```
main=substitute(paste(italic("S. aureus"), " (10^6) growth inhibition" ))
```

Any idea how to make the 6 uppercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
plot(1, main=expression(paste(italic("S. aureus"), " (10"^{6}*")"~"growth inhibition" )))
```

Comment: Any particular reason you choose * and ~ as operators in that expression?

Comment: @MikeWise `*` removes the space and `~` adds a space or use `phantom(0)`.  You can check the documentation in `?plotmath` and `demo(plotmath)`

Comment: Thanks for your held. the ~ helps. Here the final solution:main=expression(italic("S. aureus ") ~ (10^{6})  ~ "growth inhibition" )